Add a drain for basement laundry room
I'd like to redo this bathroom, but before I do I'd like to move my laundry area, which is currently in my kitchen, to the basement. I need to add a drain for this and I'm wondering if I can cut into the floor through the indicated path (red line) to join it into the bathroom drain, or whether I should run a pipe along the wall. If I go the wall route my understanding is it would have to be a larger pipe due to distance.
The shower drain is the main drain that exits my house there is another one just like it on the adjacent side of the basement.




Why do you think you need to get to that shower? What's the point of the photo with the circled stuff? Do you know where your sewer exits the house?

drains do not go up

@DIY75 Every laundry drain I've seen is up the wall a little over 3 ft with a p trap at the bottom?

@isherwood I was showing how the drain runs underground. I'm not going all the way to the shower. I dont know where the sewer exits the house because most of the basement is finished. There is another drain just like the one in the shower on the opposite side of the basement. I'm assuming it goes out there or maybe it T's up and goes out the side of the house I'm not sure.

@SeanB29 my mistake, you are correct for powered drains

Look in the sink's cabinet, where does the sink's drain go? Is the water heater located on the other side of the bathroom, the wall to the left of the sink?

@pdd yes it's right next to the sinkon the other side of the wall ill add a picture to the post of it

@SeanB29 Thanks for the photo. I've provided a quick answer as to what I would do. I can elaborate later, but for now, I have somewhere I have to go to.

I would connect to the drain line coming from the sink as low as possible. Run along the wall to where you want the laundry to be located and add a vent on the new run (if there are no existing vents to connect it to, I would use an air admittance valve).
Here's a sketch:

There are other potential issues with your current setup that might not meet the current plumbing code (s-trap and missing venting).

Thank you so much for the help, two things I had plumber stop by a year ago and asked him the same thing, he said if I did this route I would have to have 4 inch pipe down to a 3 an inch due to the distance which is about 15 ft

Also how would I get around that red supply line shown in the Pic with the egress window on the left of the stairs running up the wall?

You do not need to run this in a 4" pipe. Pipe size is determined by the load of the fixture(s) being drained into it, not the run's length.

You can offset off the wall to clear the red pipe. Regarding the stairs, if you connect to the existing pipe low enough, you should be able to pass below the top step.
